# Send hyperlink via intent

Tags: android, html, android-intent, hyperlink

Lately I have encountered a surprising issue in Android. I m getting a valid HTML document form my back-end which i would like to send as Email body.

And so most of the HTML tags are honored by the android parser except the **< a href>** tag.

An example:

```
String html = "<a href=\"" + link + "\">" + link_text + "</a>";
```

will work prefectly

However

```
String html2 = "<a href=\"" + link + "\">" + hyperlink_text + "</a>";
```

will show the hyperlink text as text and not as link.

This is the relevant snippet

```
intent.setType("text/html");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(html2));
```

I have searched the web i found many look-a-like issues and many unuseful issues.
Could it be that Android does not support this basic feature.
Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Is it correct to set the type to text/html when spanned text is being passed?

Comment: You want to send intent towards what? Another activity, or a whole different app?

Comment: @rosualin  - whole different app - mail app to be more accurate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently android does not support hyperlinks in TextView at the moment.

I have made a workaround using a WebView instead of TextView.